# Pack php into objective c

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I have php function that converts time stamp to big endian.

```
pack("N", $timestamp);
```

Is there equivalent function in objective-c?

Comment: It is "endian", not "Indian", the word refers to which end of the integer or float value comes first in memory.

Answer (score 2):

See [Byte-Order Utilities Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFByteOrderUtils/index.html)

Core Foundation Byte Order Utilities Miscellaneous Functions:

```
CFByteOrderGetCurrent
CFConvertDoubleHostToSwapped
CFConvertDoubleSwappedToHost
CFConvertFloat32HostToSwapped
CFConvertFloat32SwappedToHost
CFConvertFloat64HostToSwapped
CFConvertFloat64SwappedToHost
CFConvertFloatHostToSwapped
CFConvertFloatSwappedToHost
CFSwapInt16
CFSwapInt16BigToHost
CFSwapInt16HostToBig
CFSwapInt16HostToLittle
CFSwapInt16LittleToHost
CFSwapInt32
CFSwapInt32BigToHost
CFSwapInt32HostToBig
CFSwapInt32HostToLittle
CFSwapInt32LittleToHost
CFSwapInt64
CFSwapInt64BigToHost
CFSwapInt64HostToBig
CFSwapInt64HostToLittle
CFSwapInt64LittleToHost
```

Comment: i have a php page that makes one time password
and i want to make it in objective c to make campare between two sides results i don't know how to convert that

Comment: Zaph gave you enough information to solve this for yourself. Go read up on the Core Foundation Byte Order utilities and see if you can figure out how to use them. If you have problems, come back and post the code you've tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: A good way to make a OTP is to get random bytes. Home-build schemes are generally subject to failure. There a few ways to get random bytes on iOS.